# Dynamic JavaScript file loading and scoping: How to ensure remote script functions and variables are available at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I dynamically load and execute a JavaScript file, and then ensure that its functions and variables are available in the current scope?

Specifically, I want to load a remote JavaScript file at runtime, and then use its exported functions and variables in my application. However, since the file is loaded asynchronously, I can't simply include it with a  tag and assume that everything will be available when I need it.

What is the best way to accomplish this in JavaScript, and how can I ensure that my code waits until the remote file has finished loading before attempting to use its exports?

Assuming we have a remote JavaScript file named remote.js with the following content:

```
// remote.js
export function foo() {
  console.log("Hello from remote.js");
}
```

And we have an HTML file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dynamic JavaScript loading example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Dynamic JavaScript loading example</h1>
  <script>
    function loadScript("https://example.com/remote.js") {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = url;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
      foo(); // I want to ensure that this function is available in the current scope.
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set the script type to module, and use `import`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as a module. Use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type="module">
            const { foo } = await import('./remote.js');
            foo();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

remote.js:

```
export const foo = () => {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.textContent = 'Example';
};
```

---

If the URL to the JS file is constant (i.e. not dynamically determined) you can use a regular [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) instead.

Note that since your example code uses an absolute URL, you might be requesting the script across origins. If so then you will need CORS permission.

---

Useful background reading: [JavaScript Modules, MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Answer (score 0):

Add callback function `onload`

```
script.onload = function() { foo() };
```